# How to update holoviews Bars using an ipywidgets SelectionRangeSlider?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, holoviews

I want to select data from some pandas DataFrame in a Jupyter-notebook through a `SelectionRangeSlider` and plot the filtered data using holoviews bar chart.

Consider the following example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

import ipywidgets as widgets

start = int(datetime.datetime(2017,1,1).strftime("%s"))
end = int(datetime.datetime(2017,12,31).strftime("%s"))

size = 100
rints = np.random.randint(start, end + 1, size = size)
df = pd.DataFrame(rints, columns = ['zeit'])
df["bytes"] = np.random.randint(5,20,size=size)
df['who']= np.random.choice(['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo'], len(df))
df["zeit"] = pd.to_datetime(df["zeit"], unit='s')
df.zeit = df.zeit.dt.date

df.sort_values('zeit', inplace = True)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df.head(2)
```

This gives the test DataFrame `df`:
[image]

Let's group the data:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('who')['bytes'].sum())
data.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
data.sort_values(by="bytes", inplace=True)
data.head(2)
```

[image]

Now, create the `SelectionRangeSlider` that is to be used to filter and update the barchart.

```py
%%opts Bars [width=800 height=400 tools=['hover']]
def view2(v):
    x = df[(df.zeit > r2.value[0].date()) & (df.zeit < r2.value[1].date())]
    data = pd.DataFrame(x.groupby('who')['bytes'].sum())
    data.sort_values(by="bytes", inplace=True)
    data.reset_index(inplace=True)
    display(hv.Bars(data, kdims=['who'], vdims=['bytes']))

r2 = widgets.SelectionRangeSlider(options = options, index = index, description = 'Test')
widgets.interactive(view2, v=r2)
```

[image]

(I have already created an issue on github for the slider not displaying the label correctly, https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1759)

Problems that persist:

- the image width and size collapse to default after first update (is there a way to give `%%opts` as argument to `hv.Bars`?)
- the y-Scale should remain constant (i.e. from 0 to 150 for all updates)
- is there any optimization possible concerning speed of updates?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do it using `bokeh`: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7082